# Texshop won't compile my document when I make a change in the document

Tags: compiling, texshop

Texshop works fine for the first time compilation ("Typeset") of a .tex file, but when I change the content by writing something new or deleting a word/sentence and then run the "Typeset", it won't work. I have to close the file and start again and press "typeset", then those earlier changes will be incorporated. That is not how it worked before. Then I could make any number of changes in a document in one opening and "Typeset" would work. Not anymore!
I have attached a pic of the screen I get when I try to run "Typeset" after the first go.
Please help to sort this out. I use a 2016 MacBook Pro with Catalina OS.
Thank you,
Ioni
[image]

Comment: Can you please edit your question, and paste the relevant code, and enclose it by {} from the editor-icons? Then we can better understand, what's going on. Thanks :)

Comment: you have an older tex installation try without spaces in the filename